# yum update firefox in centos7 throwing `gpgme.GpgmeError: (7, 32870, u'Inappropriate ioctl for device')`?

Tags: centos

Doing updates in centos7 and getting following error

```
gpgme.GpgmeError: (7, 32870, u'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

Comment: Do you have a working internet connection ?

Comment: not sure!! how to check in centos machine??

Comment: You can use `ping www.google.com` , for example.

Comment: connection is okay

Comment: You're running centos7 in a lxd or another container?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem.
You can read on [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1224908) to understand the issue.
There are three solutions for this,

1. `yum update firefox | tee`
2. `yum update firefox --nogpgcheck`
3. (If running in a chroot) `mount /dev/pts; yum update firefox`

Note that "the keys will not be installed into the RPM database if you use --nogpgcheck. You end up in package being installed. But the keys not added to the database." The second method is not recommended for that reason.